# In Delphi, how do you define a static struct containing an array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, struct, static, record

I'm trying to create a complex structure to contain program data which should not change during the execution. I have the following code, which doesn't work, but it conveys the point of what I'm attempting to do:

```
type

  TTestFieldProperties = record
    FieldType: Integer;
  end;

  TTestFieldPropertyArray = array of TTestFieldProperties;

  TTestTypeProperties = record
    TestType: Integer;
    TestFieldProperties: TTestFieldPropertyArray;
  end;

const

  TestTypeProperties: array [0..1] of TTestTypeProperties = (
    (
      TestType: 2361;
      TestFieldProperties: nil
    ), (
      TestType: 3526;
      TestFieldProperties: /*array [0..1] of TTestFieldProperty???*/
      (
        (
          FieldType: 3
        ), (
          FieldType: 7
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

In this example, I have a record called TTestTypeProperties record which contains an array of TTestFieldProperty records. I'm trying to create a constant structure which defines an array of TTestTypeProperties records. So in essence, an array of records which contains another array of records.

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting to do?

The code above does not compile, because I cannot figure out how to deal with the TestFieldProperties field. Does it require a bounds definition?

Answer (score 2):

`array of ...` is a *dynamic* array, it is allocated only at runtime, so you can't declare a constant for it at compile time.

What you can do instead, though, is declare a separate array, and then have `TTestTypeProperties` hold a raw pointer to it, eg:

```
type

  TTestFieldProperties = record
    FieldType: Integer;
  end;

  PTestFieldProperties = ^TTestFieldProperties;

  TTestTypeProperties = record
    TestType: Integer;
    TestFieldProperties: PTestFieldProperties;
  end;

const

  TestFieldPropertiesArray: array [0..1] of TTestFieldProperties = (
    (
      FieldType: 3
    ), (
      FieldType: 7
    )
  );

  TestTypeProperties: array [0..1] of TTestTypeProperties = (
    (
      TestType: 2361;
      TestFieldProperties: nil
    ), (
      TestType: 3526;
      TestFieldProperties: @TestFieldPropertiesArray[0]
    )
  );
```